# How to read a line from a text file for input in matlab

Tags: matlab, text-files, octave

I am generating some 3D points and saving in a text file. Next I want to take those points as input for another code. here is my text file:

```
*******OUTPUT 1 for p=0.01 5x5x5********
1 1 4 ;3 2 4 ; 
*******OUTPUT 2 for p=0.01 5x5x5********
2 1 3 ;1 4 4 ; 
*******OUTPUT 3 for p=0.01 5x5x5********
2 1 3 ;1 4 4 ;
```

For output 1 p=0.01 (1,1,4) and (3,2,4) are my points. I want to match the output number and p value and then grab those points(for that output number and p value) as my input of another code.I want to do something like below:

`if(*******OUTPUT %d for p=%0.2f 5x5x5*******)`

```
    points = will take the points after that line
```

`end`

But do not know how to do that.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need exactly that format or you can change it? There would definitely be easier solutions then.

Comment: @Matt: i don,t need exactly that format. but for each p value i want to take all the points as input

Comment: I don't know your data-model behind the variables. Can the data be organized as a table somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This code will extract the **output** value, **p** value and the **points** into three separate arrays.

```
output=[];
p=[];
points=[];

% open file
fid = fopen('test.txt');

% read the file line by line
tline = fgetl(fid);

% if the line is not empty
while ischar(tline)

    % if it is the 'output' line
    if strcmp(tline(1:13),'*******OUTPUT')

        % extract the output number from the string
        output = [output, sscanf(tline,'%*s %i %*s%*f %*s')];

        % extract p value
        p = [p, sscanf(tline,'%*s %*i%*8c%f %*s')];

    % if it is the 'points' line
    else

        % extract points, sscanf output is transposed
        points = [points; sscanf(tline,'%i %i %i%*2c%i %i %i %*s')'];

    end

    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

% close file
fclose(fid);
```

Once you have the values extracted, you can do whatever you need to do with it.